# How to do a special sort in C++?

Tags: c++

How can someone make a special sort for the following situation:
There is a deck of cards. You have a 2D array that was created from the combination of two 1D arrays : one that represents the suit and another that represents the rank as such:

```
string suit[4] = { "H", "D", "S", "C" };
string rank[13] = { "A", "K", "Q", "J", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2" };
```

They are combined to create a 2D array(`[4][13])` using this combination,

```
suit[i1] + "-" + rank[i2]
```

After shuffiling the cards, the array is no longer in order and should be returned to its original order where the Hearts goes first and then Diamonds and so on. Similarly, each group should have the ace first and then the king and so on.

How can one make a *special sort* for this situation?

**My thoughts:**

We first have to read the array. The first element should be compared to the next. The tricky part is this very comparison. What type of grounds should we use in the comparison. Lets assume we have a D-A and then H-2. So, we first read the first character of the string which is D and compare it to the next one. If they are the same, we should jump to the third entry of the string "D-A". If not, we make a comparison. Is there an easier way? How can one *define a comparison*, saying that H>D and A>K? And how can one *implement this method using the 2D array* because a simple sort only works on 1D arrays and not 2D.

Comment: since you are using c++, why not use a vector, and just write a comparison function?

Comment: Isn't a vector equivalent to a 1D array? Furthermore, how can I make a comparison of an element in an entry to another element in another entry.

Comment: You could make a `std::vector` of `std::pair` where the first element is the suit and the second element is the value.  Since `std::pair` has a less-than operator you can use `std::sort` on the vector without writing your own comparison operator.

Comment: @GWW But that won't allow indexing like `v[2][9]` to get the "9th" card of suit "2" (if OP cared about that)

Comment: How exactly are you shuffling your 2D array?

Comment: @alecbenzer A swap where the indicies are assigned random numbers. This is iterated several times

Comment: @GWW what does the pair function do exactly?

Comment: @user29568 Is there a reason you want to shuffle a 2D array instead of just a flat list of cards? With your original (unsorted) 2D array, the 2 indexes have special meaning. But once you've shuffled them it seems like the cards are now in arbitrary rows/columns.

Comment: @alecbenzer They must be rearranged back to the first row having only Hearts... However, I think a 1D array would be the same thing but just with 52 straight elements. I was insisting on a 2D array to be consistent.

Comment: @user29568 Why not just keep the 2D array and never shuffle it, and have a separate 1D array for shuffling/re-sorting (and then you can use the proposed `vector<pair<suit, rank>>` solution)?

Comment: IMO, representing a card is much easier with a `Card` class.  See my answer below.

Comment: How do you pass around cards using your representation?  Two variables?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yup, two variables. I am reading your answer and trying to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why I recommended creating a Card class.

```
class Card
{
  public:
    bool operator < (const Card& other_card) const;
//  private:
    suit m_suit;
    rank m_rank;
};

bool Card::operator<(const Card& other_card) const
{
  bool  is_less_than;
  if (m_suit == other_card.m_suit)
  {
      is_less_than = m_rank < other_card.m_rank;
  }
  else
  {
    is_less = m_suit < other_card.m_suit;
  }
  return is_less_than;
}
```

By overloading `operator <` you can use the operator to compare `Card` objects:

```
Card player1;
player1.rank = two;
player1.suit = spade;
Card player2;
player2.rank = three;
player2.suit = spade;
Card player3;
player3.rank = 4;
player3.suit = club;

if (player1 < player2)
{
  cout << "player1 < player2\n";
}
else
{
  cout << "player1 not less than player2\n";
}

if (player 1 < player3)
{
  cout << "player1 < player3\n";
}
else
{
  cout << "player1 not less than player3\n";
}
```

Also, the `sort` methods and functions will automatically use this method, so you don't have to write an comparison function.

If you also overload `operator==`, you can easily define all the comparison operators:

```
operator!= : return !(*this == other_card);
operator>= : return !(*this <  other_card);
operator<= : return (*this < other_card) || (*this == other_card);
operator>  : return !(*this <= other_card);
```

Or you include the Boost Library (header file) which will code up all the remaining operations for you.

**Edit 1:  Deck of cards**
Representing a card as a single object, simplifies your program.  You can use the `Card` in standard containers:

```
typedef std::vector<Card> Card_Container;
Card_Container deck(52);
Card_Container poker_hand(5);
Card_Container blackjack_hand;
```

The `std::vector` allows for easy implementation of card containers that need dynamic size adjustment, like a hand in BlackJack, War, or "Go Fish".

**Printing of a Card**
You can overload `operator<<` to print the card any way you want in a style that applies to all cards.  This makes output simple:

```
cout << "Blackjack hand:\n";
for (Card_Container::iterator iter = blackjack_hand.begin();
     iter != blackjack_hand.end();
     ++iter)
{
  cout << *iter << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on the comment by GWW:

```
enum suit { club, spade, diamond, heart };

enum rank {
   two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight,
   nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace
};

using card = std::pair<suit, rank>;

int main ()
{
    std::vector<card> deck{
       {diamond, five}, {spade, ace},
       {club, two}, {spade, nine}
    };
    std::sort(deck.begin(), deck.end());
    for (auto c : deck)
        cout << c.first << " " << c.second << endl;
}
```

That is, separate internal representation from appearance, and use `enum` for the former; a custom `operator<<` could take care of the latter. A `card` based on `std::pair` uses its `operator<` that compares lexicographically, which is what you want if I get it correctly.

This assumes you store a deck in a one-dimensional `vector`. I think this would be more convenient than two-dimensional in most situations. In fact, I can't see why you insist on 2D when you want to sort.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the pair function does? And to answer your question: I was  insisting on a 2D array for consistency and clarity. However, like you said sorting is far easier with a 1D array.

Comment: @user29568 [`pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) isn't a function, it's a struct that just contains two elements. It has a pre-defined `operator<` that lets you compare them, and this means that contains of `pair`s can be sorted with the `std::sort` function.

Comment: It's not a function, it's a type. As the name says, a `pair<X,Y>` is a pair (a struct) of one object of type `X` and another of type `Y`.

Comment: How does the pair type and enum suit/rank define a specific sort. Does it use  the type enum as a reference?

Comment: @user29568 Check out the [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) defined for [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

Comment: @user29568 Also, `enums` are compared according to order of appearance in their definition.